The method 'sorted' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable'
I'm trying to sort a list using the .sorted() method, but I always get the message that the method is not defined.
According to this documentation the method should exist.
The following code snippet should clarify my function:
  Future<List<EventInfo>> getEventInfoListFromAPI() async {
    final response = await Api.shared.getEventResourceApi().getEvents();
    final list = response.data?.data;
    if (list != null) {
      return Future.wait(list.where((item) =>
          // Do some filtering
          true).map((item) async {
        // Fetch some other stuff from API
        ...
        // Return EventInfo object
        return EventInfo(item.tile, item.date, null, []);
      }));
    }
    return [];
  }

list is of type BuiltList<Event>? (in case that matters).
I would now like to add a .sorted after the .map to sort the data, but then I get the error mentioned.
flutter --version returns:
Flutter 3.24.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 80c2e84975 (9 days ago) • 2024-07-30 23:06:49 +0700
Engine • revision b8800d88be
Tools • Dart 3.5.0 • DevTools 2.37.2

I'm using Visual Studio Code, if this is relevant.

Make sure to import collection pkg

@Md.YeasinSheikh: That did it. Thanks!
